# Open a new panel via a button Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I saw a lot of post on StackOverflow relating to this, but unable to solve my problem.
I want to open a new Panel by clicking a button.

Here is how i try to do it

```
    parameterButton = new JButton("Parametres");
    parameterButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            createParameterPanel = new DisplayParameterPanel();
            createParameterPanel.setVisible(true);
            add(createParameterPanel);

        };
    });
    add(parameterButton);
```

When I click the parameterButton it doesn't open.
How can I open a new panel.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You don't need to create an instance of `DisplayParameterPanel` every time on action event of `parameterButton`. Just create once in your class context.
2. make it visible and invisible using consecutively `setVisible(true)` and `setVisible(false)`.
3. use `JLayeredPane` to control the layer of the `DisplayParameterPanel`: A layered pane is a Swing container that provides a third dimension for positioning components: depth, also known as Z order. When adding a component to a layered pane, you specify its depth as an integer. The higher the number, closer the component is to the `"top"` position within the container.

Check out [**`How to Use Layered Pane`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html)

Comment: If you have hard time to understand how `JLayeredPane` will work for this use case, feel free to ask, i will try to provide a demo :)

Answer (score 2):

> I want to open a new Panel by clicking a button.

Use a CardLayout. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more information and a working example.

Comment: A possible solution too, but it is not making sense to me, what would he want to do with *one button* and `card layout`. I have asked him almost 40 mins before what really he wants but nope, no response.